# Java: SAX ignores schema validation

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have the following the following xml schema module.xsd:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xs:element name="module2">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="temp" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> 
</xs:schema>
```

and I have the following xml document module.xml:

```
<module xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="module.xsd">
    <init-param name="foo" value="boo"/>
</module>
```

And this the code I create parser:

```
Schema xmlSchema = null;
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
xmlSchema = schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getResource(MODULE_PATH));
if (xmlSchema==null){
    System.out.println("Schema NULL");
}else{
    System.out.println("Schema NOT NULL");
}
SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
parserFactory.setSchema(xmlSchema);
parserFactory.setValidating(true);
parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
SAXParser saxParser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
```

I get `Schema NOT NULL` and my file is parsed without any probmes. But I wait the exception as the schema is wrong. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parser encounters schema validations it will not throw an exception but report the violation to its `ErrorHandler` which in most cases will be the `DefaultHandler` passed to `SaxParser.parse()`:

If you want validation errors thrown as exception then override `DefaultHandler.error`:

```
saxParser.parse(new File("module.xml"), new DefaultHandler() {
    public void error (SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        throw e;
    }
});
```